# Clarity Regarding Dependent Events in Probability

Tags: probability

Given the Scenario in Communication:
Let $R^∗_f$ and $R^∗_n$ denote the target rates of the far and near user. Then, the probability of outage of the near user data is given by,
$P_n=P_r(R_n<R^∗_n)$
The far user's signal can be decoded successfully only if the near user's data is decoded correctly. Therefore, the outage probability of the far user is given as follows:
$P_f=P_r(R_n<R^∗n)+P_r(R_n>R^∗_n,R_f<R^∗_f)$

Is this correct expression or we need to multiply the probabilities in dependent events.
(Note: The relations within the bracket are verified regarding achievable rates, the question is specific to $+$ (Plus) sign.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

The two events are disjoint, so the expression for the probability of failure as you mentioned is correct. Among four possible outcome, {SS, SF, FS, FF}, only one, {SS}, constitutes a successful end-to-end connection. If the first link fails, it doesn't matter whether the second link is failed or successfully connected, hence the first term in $P_f$. But if the first link is connected successfully, the overall link fails if the second link fails, hence the second term in $P_f$.

You are good to go. :)